# Customising IRB console for gem

Tags: ruby, irb

I'd like to extend the default console application that is built as standard with `bundle gem` by applying some of the IRB config options.

[Looking at the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html#module-IRB-label-Configuration), I can see that it should be possible for instance to change the prompt, and this works fine on an interactive session. For example I can play with the displayed prompt like this:

```
2.1.4 :001 > conf.prompt_mode=:SIMPLE
=> :SIMPLE
>>
?> conf.prompt_mode=:DEFAULT
=> :DEFAULT
irb(main):004:0>
```

However, I cannot find how to translate this into syntax for use in the console app. For example this script:

```
require 'irb'
IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE] = :SIMPLE
IRB.start
```

Just starts with the generic configured prompt:

```
2.1.4 :001 >
```

I have spent some time trying to find an example use of IRB for a custom repl without loading global defaults, but not found anything I can copy from.

I can see that the undocumented method `IRB.setup` has something to do with this, it is setting all the config somehow. Is my only option to write my own version of `IRB.start` that applies my desired config after calling `IRB.setup`, or is there support for what I want to do built-in but not documented in standard location?

---

E.g. the following works, but I feel it's a bit heavy handed extending IRB module this way (and also prone to failing if IRB internals change).

```
require 'irb'

def IRB.custom_start custom_conf = {}
  STDOUT.sync = true

  IRB.setup(nil)

  custom_conf.each do |k,v|
    IRB.conf[k] = v
  end

  if @CONF[:SCRIPT]
    irb = IRB::Irb.new(nil, @CONF[:SCRIPT])
  else
    irb = IRB::Irb.new
  end

  @CONF[:IRB_RC].call(irb.context) if @CONF[:IRB_RC]
  @CONF[:MAIN_CONTEXT] = irb.context

  trap("SIGINT") do
    irb.signal_handle
  end

  begin
    catch(:IRB_EXIT) do
      irb.eval_input
    end
  ensure
    irb_at_exit
  end
end

IRB.custom_start :PROMPT_MODE => :SIMPLE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can apply custom configurations in two ways.

The first one is to use [irbrc file](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html#module-IRB-label-Configuration). It may be tricky in building console application (calling `IRB.start` from the ruby file instead of `irb` from the console).

The second one is the approach that you have described in the post. You can write your own `IRB::start` method based on [the original one](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html#method-c-start). There are exactly the same potential issues as in using undocumented API - it can break in the future with newer versions of irb.

You should think if you really need to build a console application on the top of irb. For example you can solve this problem using [`Pry`](https://github.com/pry/pry). It allows to [define configuration](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Customization-and-configuration) before starting interactive session.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me at Pry again. I looked at it before, but the focus on debugging features made me think it was not suitable. It may well be better than `irb` for me, even if just for the properly documented support to change config programatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'irb'
IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE] = :SIMPLE
IRB.start
```

The approach above doesn't work because `conf[:PROMPT_MODE]` gets over-riden in a method called `IRB.init_config` [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/irb/init.rb#L107)

When `IRB.start` is called, it calls `IRB.setup` which in turn calls the method `IRB.init_config` -- which over-rides `conf[:PROMPT_MODE]` setting.

---

Here is one approach which solves the problem (relies on internal knowledge of the implementation).

```
require 'irb'

module IRB
  singleton_class.send(:alias_method, :old_setup, :setup)

  def IRB.setup(ap_path)
    IRB.old_setup(ap_path)

    conf[:PROMPT_MODE] = :SIMPLE
  end
end

IRB.start
```

Comment: This is cleaner than my solution, but does share the problem that it works with the implementation, not the "official" interface.

Comment: @NeilSlater Yeah, that's why I said it "relies on internal knowledge of the implementation". I guess, `setup` is a public method, hence part of the public interface. It's just not documented very well.